# Появление блоков по setTimeout

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Задача 1. Каждую секунду в видимой области появляются квадратики с соответствующими числами. 
Задача 2. При появлении числа 5 всё начинается сначала.

```js
setTimeout(function (){
  var block = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for(i=0; i < block[i].length; i++) {
    block[0].style.display = 'block';
  }
  i++;
},1000)
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 0;
  
}
li {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="block">1</li>
  <li class="block">2</li>
  <li class="block">3</li>
  <li class="block">4</li>
  <li class="block">5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Почитайте какой-нибудь учебник по основам javascript. Для начала, вы пытаетесь использовать несуществующую переменную `i`. Если предположить, что она есть, то `block[i]` возвращает HTML-элемент, а у HTML-элемента не существует свойства `length`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сделал вот так:

```js
const blocks = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('li'));

function callBlock(i) {
     if(i <= blocks.length - 1) {
         blocks[i].style.display = 'flex';
         setTimeout(()=> {
            callBlock(++i);
         },1000)
     } else {
         for(let el of blocks) {
             el.style.display = 'none';
         }
         setTimeout(()=> {
            i = 0;
            callBlock(i);
         },1000)
     }
}

callBlock(0);
```

```css
ul {
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="block">1</li>
  <li class="block">2</li>
  <li class="block">3</li>
  <li class="block">4</li>
  <li class="block">5</li>
</ul>
```

- пример на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6k3homnu/2/)

Answer (score 2):

```js
function showNext(index) {
  var blocks = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  if (index >= blocks.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
      blocks[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    index = 0;
  } else {
    blocks[index].style.display = 'block';
    index++;
  }

  setTimeout(showNext, 1000, index);
}

setTimeout(showNext, 1000, 0);
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="block">1</li>
  <li class="block">2</li>
  <li class="block">3</li>
  <li class="block">4</li>
  <li class="block">5</li>
</ul>
```